# Is there a way to cleanup invalid attributes from HTML?

Tags: java, html, xml, dom

I have a need where I am trying to create *org.w3c.dom.Document* Object from a HTML string, using *javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder*. Here there are possibilities of having invalid attributes and their values in that HTML String. So Is there any way or Java util to clean up only the invalid attributes from the HTML? Tried *JSOUP* clean up, in that its cleaning based on the whitelisted tags and attributes. But my need is to clean up only the invalid attributes (as per HTML5 standard).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NotebookException {

        String text = "<div dir=\"ltr\">﻿<link href=\"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:light:bold\" rel=\"stylesheet\" \\=\"\">";

        try(ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes()))
        {       
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(bais));
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
    }
```

In Above code, the html string with LINK tag has invalid attribute '\' and its value '""' (empty double quotes). Needs to clean this html which parsing to a Document object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
String.replaceAll("[unwanted chars]","");
```

Refer [replaceAll tutorial page](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall) for more details especially on the escape characters.

These things will work on predefined symbols only, in order to make your system intelligent and keep on updating itself with every new invalid symbol encountered you will need to write a method to store such new symbols in an appropriate data structure while handling the relevant exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't process any data unless you know what data you need to process. This applies to your task just as to any other. If you want to process dirty data, you need to specify what kind of dirt you expect to encounter and how you propose to deal with it. That will determine the approach adopted.

It may be that the kind of processing you need to do can be done by an existing library such as TagSoup or validator.nu. Or it might be that it can be done using regular expressions. Without a specification of the task, we can't know.

Consider an example. Suppose the input file contains `"< < < < > > > >"` What would you want your program to do with it?

***...LATER***

From your comment it sounds as if the HTML is "well formed but not valid", to borrow XML terminology. This means you could consider an XSLT solution:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="saxon:parse-html('input.bad.html')"/>
```

...

```
<xsl:template match="a/@href | */@class | */@id | .... (:all valid attributes:)">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* (: attributes not in the above list :)">
  <!-- no action (drop the attribute) -->
</xsl:template>
```

`saxon:parse-html()` is a Saxon XSLT extension. With other processors there may be some other way of parsing HTML into an XML DOM and using the XML DOM as input to the processor.

Comment: I want my code to check whether the tags are HTML4/HTML5 allowed tags, if it is then check for the attributes and remove unsupported attributes respect to that tag.